# REACT API Call and NODE.JS proxy server error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, proxy

I'm trying to start a node proxy server in order to call an API through it and apply it to my react app. I don't know what I'm doing wrong when starting the server, but I can't make it work. Here's the error:

> > Error: Network Error
> > at createError (createError.js:16)
> > at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:99) console. @ index.js:1 overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:4049 (anonymous)
> > @ App.js:16 :3001/:1 Failed to load resource:
> > net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED index.js:1 Error: Network Error
> > at createError (createError.js:16)
> > at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:99) console. @ index.js:1 overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:4049 (anonymous)
> > @ App.js:16 :3001/:1 Failed to load resource:
> > net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

my server.js:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const { default: axios } = require("axios");
const port = 3001;
const http = require("http");

app.options("*", cors());

app.get("/", async (res) => {
  const response = await axios.request("https://superheroapi.com/api/apikey");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.send(response);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("express on port 3001");
});
```

my app.js:

```
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';


function App() {

const getAPI =  {
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:3001/"
}
axios.request(getAPI)
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});


  return (
    <>
    <h1>hello world</h1>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I start the app I just type in the terminal "npm start" but I don't know if that command starts the server as well.

PACKAGE.JSON

```
{
  "name": "amadeo-dlp-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: show your package.json file as well

Comment: READY! I just put it

Comment: is the console logging "express on port 3001"?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create the server and pass it the express app.

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const cors = require('cors');
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const axios = require('axios');

app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

app.get("/", async (res) => {
    const response = await axios.request("https://superheroapi.com/api/apikey");
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
         res.send(response);
     });

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') throw error;
  const bind = typeof port === 'string' ? 'Pipe ' + port : 'Port ' + port;
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

function onListening() {
  const addr = server.address();
  const bind = typeof addr === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + addr : 'port ' + addr.port;
  console.log('Express server listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: OP didnt even use the http dependency, i think the error is caused because he didnt initialize the express server

Answer (score 0):

From your `package.json` it looks like the script `npm start` is just initializing your front-end only (react app), which basically means the express server is not running to actually handle any api calls. you're gonna have to run your express server using `node server.js` (if the file is nested use appropriate directory)

Comment: I tried but it says Error: Cannot find module MODULE_NOT_FOUND is there something i need to install first?

Comment: i suggest you to move your express app to a new folder and install all dependencies & package files there